# Xtrareports Bands Size and Location

Tags: c#, reporting-services, devexpress, report, xtrareport

How could I set at runtime my bands size and location ?

```
Bands.Add(_reportHeader);
_reportHeader.Height = 300;
Bands.Add(_pageHeader);
_pageHeader.LocationF = new PointF(0, _reportHeader.HeightF);
```

When I do this, the heightf and locationf of both bands dont change, they keep constant.

Comment: Iam not that sure why you cant change the height of your Band. But to change the Location makes no sense. A PageHeader is displayed on top of every ReportPage so where else you want to place? This wont work. Maybe you can change the height if you set the PaperKind Property of the Report to Custom.

Comment: I found the mistake, the band height is set to the bottom most control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to worry about the automatic size, since the bottom most control will say what size the band will have. For automatic sizing, just do like this:

```
_reportHeader.HeightF = 0f;
Bands.Add(_reportHeader);
_pageHeader.HeightF = 0f;
Bands.Add(_pageHeader);
```